# unable install google earth in ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: apt

When i try to install google earth with gdebi or another software manager i' ve a dependency issue with ia32-libs. I tried to found them at the repositories, but i' did not find them. What should i do to install google earth on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?
Thank you
Pedro Manteigas

Comment: From where did you downloaded this package? What's the exact command that you are trying to install with?

Answer (score 2):

Please do for 64bit:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxext6:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386
cd /tmp && wget http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

after the third command you will see some errors then run the fourth command and answer yes when asked to download more packages.

I tested this on my computer and it works perfectly. 
[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html)

For 32bit systems just download google earth and install it with software center or Gdebi.

Comment: I just tested it and it works. Also, if you get a message saying google-earth-stable was not installed correctly after running the third command, that is normal. Just puttin' it out there.